# Как сделать движение персонажа на определенное количестов пикселей? Godot (Gdscript)

Tags: godot, move

Я пытаюсь сделать пошаговое передвижение персонажа, чтобы при нажатии например W он передвинулся на 16 пикселей вперед при скорости 4п/c(не моментально), блокируя возможность передвигаться в другие направления. У меня была мысль высчитывать разницу между начальными и последними координатами, после передвигать персонажа, пока она не будет равна нулю, но я понял что при столкновении со стеной он просто будет бесконечно двигаться, так еще и появляется погрешность между координатами, из-за чего персонаж потихоньку сходит с центра тайла. Поэтому я хочу узнать как сделать, чтобы персонаж просто проходил определенное расстояние, не зависимо от его координат(звучит странно, но надеюсь кто нибудь понял о чем я).